# How do i get the UPC code from barcode scanner?

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, zxing

I'm new here to stack overflow though I've been reading for quite a while on PHP and some android questions I had.

My question is how can I get the data from barcode scanner (just the UPC code and image) so I can insert it into a MySQL table?

I'll figure out the MySQL table insert on my own but this is just killing me! I'm pretty new to android apps and such but I'm very determined to get my idea off the ground and start selling it in the market. So far I am able to initiate the scanner thanks to Zxing's URL I saw on their WIKI http://zxing.appspot.com/scan

That initiates the scanner on the click of a button in my app. It reads and works but I don't know how to get the data from the results.

I have looked up and down that article... i get that i need to pretty much just insert code into different places, however on that article page what does it mean by put this in your activity?

```
`public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,    resultCode,         intent);
  if (scanResult != null) {
    // handle scan result
  }
  // else continue with any other code you need in the method
  ...
}`
```

Also where do i put this code?

```
`IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity);
integrator.initiateScan();`
```

Comment: What kind of device is the barcode scanner seen as? Such as USB or Bluetooth HID?

Comment: @DanS zxing is a library that uses the phone's camera to scan barcodes.

Comment: Oh I thought you were referring to a physical device.

Comment: I'm trying to get a scan of a barcode then use zxing's library to find the product via the UPC and then just literally copy the results (image and UPC code, and name of item of course)

Answer (score 4):

Review the [Scanning via Intent](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) article from the ZXing Google Code page. For information about how to handle a return value from the ZXing scanning activity

Comment: I have looked up and down that article... i get that i need to pretty much just insert code into different places, however on that article page what does it mean by put this in your activity?  

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {  
  IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
  if (scanResult != null) 
    // handle scan result
  }
  // else continue with any other code you need in the method
  ...
}

Answer (score 3):

```
 IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity);
 integrator.initiateScan();
```

this codes are needed to be where you need to call scanner... For example, if you have a button, you can put this line into it's OnClickListener.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,    resultCode,         intent);
if (scanResult != null) {
// handle scan result
}
 // else continue with any other code you need in the method
...
 }
```

And this one should exist in your app, as a method...